# Under what conditions do tomatoes grow best?

Tags: vegetables, tomatoes

Our garden is in partial shade, and I am wondering how much sun tomatoes need to grow best?

Answer (score 1):

They seem to need between 6 and 10 hours of direct sun to grow best, depending on the growth stage they are at.

See [here](https://dengarden.com/gardening/How-Much-Sun-Do-Tomato-Plants-Need) (and many other sites seem to be in agreement on my cursory survey) for details.